# Can PDFium read & render PostScript files?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, postscript, pdfium

I am using Google's PDFium library and would like to know if it is able to read and render PostScript files?

Any direction is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware PDFium **only** handles PDF files. Of course you can use Ghostscript to create a PDF file from a PostScript file.

Comment: Thank you, KenS. I am currently doing that. Could I impose a GhostScript question on you, if you might know? I'm using a single gsdll32.dll function gsapi_init_with_args() to convert PS files to PDF, and it works well. However, I've been trying to trim the fat from the 400+ files in the GhostScript folder which seem to be dependencies for the DLL. Are they all really required?

Comment: Well, that depends..... The resources (everything under ghostpdl/Resource) are built into the ROM file system, so you don't need those *unless* you ever want to modify any of them, or look at them to see the usage syntax (eg cidfmap, fontmap.GS). Everything in ghostpdl/lib and ghostpdl/toolbin are useful extras, none of them are dependencies they do additional 'stuff' which you may find useful. Everything under ghostpdl/doc is (unsurprisingly perhaps) documentation. Everything under ghostpdl/examples are examples. Is there a reason to want to remove files ?

Comment: Oh, I see you are on WIndows, so the Resource files are not included, nor are the headers for rebuilding. Some of the other stuff is to do with our complying with the terms of open-source licences. Since Ghostscript is licensed under the AGPL, we obviously try very hard to be good citizens ourselves.

Comment: Thank you very much, KenS!  It works now; apparently it did not require any dependencies. Could I please refer to another one of your much earlier posts? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406396/building-ghostscript-9-04-win32/41805307#41805307) I've posted a question there and was hoping you could help me there too. Once again, thank you.

Comment: Correction to my earlier comment; the PDFium DLL, gsdll32.dll, does require its dependencies. The reason it worked was because GhostScript was installed on one of my development machines which set and pointed all the required environment variables back to the installation folder - on other machines it did not work. However, for the sole purpose of converting PostScript files to PDF format, only a handful of .PS libraries from the LIB folder were required.

Comment: Can you list which ones were required ? There should not be any from that folder and we need to address that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I seem to be mixing the two up. I wrote PDFium DLL when I meant GhostScript DLL (gsdll32.dll). I'm using v.7 of GhostScript as the DLL is only 3MB, as compared to the 16MB of the current v.9.2. I found some earlier versions as well, with slightly smaller DLLs, but I've not been able to build those. The LIB folder contains 281 files (total 1.7MB), but I've trimmed it down to just 65 .PS files (total 700KB). I'm sure that further elimination is possible, but I've kept all the .PS files that begin with gsxxxxxx.ps and pdfxxxxxx.ps.

Comment: I really, really wouldn't use such an old version of Ghostscript. There have been numerous bug fixes, including serious security vulnerabilities, not to mention performance enhancements and new features. This is **especially** true of the PostScript to PDF conversion. It is absolutely not possible to fix bugs in a version of Ghostscript which is at *least* 14 years old! I'm not surprised that an old version requires files from that folder, a new version should not. Seriously, please reconsider, I would absolutely not ship (or use) such an old version.

Comment: Assuming that a later version of the DLL is able to work independently, is there any way to rebuild it smaller? And would the license still be AGPL open source?

Comment: You can strip stuff out, certainly (CMaps, fallback fonts) at the cost of functionality. The droidsans fallback font alone is 3.6 MB. Of course if you remove that then missing CIDFonts will simply fail to render. CMaps are another 6 Mb, but without those you can't create CIDKeyed fonts either so its the same problem. Fonts are another 4Mb. I assure you none of this is present simply to make the DLL larger, it all adds functionality which I think you will sorely miss in its absence. Not to mention the numerous bugs you are going to end up with using an archaic version. Can't answer the GPL.

Comment: In short, the difference in size you are seeing is because stuff which is stored on disk (or simply not present) in version 7 is included in the DLL with the current version. If you ship version 7 without all these support files (which I'm sure are at least mostly present in that version) then you will lose the same functionality, you just haven't run across any cases yet. I **very** strongly advise you to use a current version of Ghostscript, with all the support files built in. I believe you will have quality/functionality problems if you don't.

Comment: Compelling points. Can't conceivably unit-test every conversion possibility, and wouldn't want to hit any roadblocks in production. But a 16MB-DLL is pretty huge. Thank you for your great input, KenS. Truly appreciated.